# Trying to get a unique version of a List of strings that is case insensitive

Tags: java, list

I have a list of strings, and I want to make a unique version of it in order to calculate a type token ratio. It needs to be case insensitive in order to function properly, and I'm unsure as to how I should approach it. This is in java, which I forgot to mention in the title. This is the java.util.List, not the java.awt.List.
Edit: I decided to talk more about the code. The class this is necessary for has an object called Case that has the original list.

```
Book Case = new Book(String x);
public float getTTRatio(){
//insert creation of unique list here.
}
```

The List is called words, and is to be filled with the words of a text file, so the call for the List I need to make unique is Case.words. I need to make it so that I can do this as the return value for the method, where unique is the name of the List that is filled with only the unique words and is case insensitive:

```
return unique.size/Case.words.size();
```

Comment: Any code to show?

Comment: I've edited the original question to better show what I'm going for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only need the size you can do that with a `Set` of upper case words:

```
Set<String> unique = new HashSet<>();
for (String word : Case.words) {
    // Adds only if the same uppercase String wasn't added before
    unique.add(word.toUpperCase());  
}
return (float) unique.size() / Case.words.size(); // convert one of the ints to float
```

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for, thank you very much.